# access several fragments from one float button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have searched through several articles but couldn't find what I need. I need to implement one float button to access different fragments. Can anyone help in that?

this is my float button in the MainActivity

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewPager);
            String tag = currentFragment.getTag();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[InventoryFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlhLD.png)

[RecipeFragement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne4Pe.png)

Comment: add a picture how you want it

Comment: These two fragments are having the same floating button which will open a different activity depending on the which is being viewed.

Comment: @Wissam you can specify what do you need?

Comment: @ShivamKumar I need the right code which will allow this single floating button to work on all the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to have references to all the fragments you want access to in the class you have this code written (MainActivity) outside of the FloatingActionButton listener.

Or, because fragments can contain other fragments, make a main fragment that contains all of the others and just reference that

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `onClick` method

```
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.viewPager);
            String tag = currentFragment.getTag();
        switch (tag) {
            case Inventory:
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
                break;
            case Recipe:
                //what do you want to do
                break;
        }
```

Another way would be to